# Kendo Grid Validation Message Alignment issue for DropDown

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-validator

I am stuck with an alignment issue of Kendo Grid Validation Message for dropdown. For text-box, validation message shows correctly and for dropdown it shows partially as the next row overlaps the validation message as in the below image.
I have tried many workarounds and couldn't fix this. Please help.

[Comparison Image for text box and dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31y9K.png)

[Download Test Solution](https://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/d328a9fc-18be-4475-9641-cf82c7ae267c_test-application.zip?sfvrsn=496edf5_0)

Comment: It's hard to provide solution without code. Try `css` work around.

Comment: Hi MUT, I have added the Solution. I have tried with CSS and nothing is working as expected for dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around. You can use:

```
.k-tooltip {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This will make the validation message positioned on a fixed place even though you scroll the page and confuse the user.

Comment: Just a work around. However you can use your own `custom validation` and the `append` error to `Dom`. See [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/inline-edit---validation-not-working-on-dropdownlist) thread